# async await problem to get video frames in Javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, webcam

Just tried to get face landmark via web browser using mediapipe (not using the Camera api from Mediapipe).
My code is working only if I call the mediapipe api when clicking a button or using a delay.

html:

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/camera_utils/camera_utils.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils/control_utils.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/drawing_utils/drawing_utils.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh/face_mesh.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>

  <body>
    <video id="input_video"></video>
    <canvas id="output_canvas" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas>
    <button id="run" class="btn">Click here to Run</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
window.onload = function () {
  const videoElement = document.getElementById("input_video");

  initVideo(videoElement, 320, 180);
};

const faceMesh = new FaceMesh({
  locateFile: (file) => {
    return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh/${file}`;
  },
});
faceMesh.setOptions({
  maxNumFaces: 1,
  minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
  minTrackingConfidence: 0.5,
});

const onResults = function (res) {
  const landmarks = res.multiFaceLandmarks;
  console.log(landmarks);
  if (!landmarks) return;
};

async function run_landmarks(video_elt) {
  await faceMesh.send({ image: video_elt });
  requestAnimationFrame(run(video_elt));
}

function initVideo(video, w, h) {
  if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    const constraints = { video: { width: w, height: h, facingMode: "user" } };

    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function (stream) {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
        videoElement = video;
        run_landmarks(video);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Unable to access the camera/webcam.", error);
      });
  } else {
    console.error("MediaDevices interface not available.");
  }
}

faceMesh.onResults(onResults);
```

When launching this code, run_landmarks is launched immediately, before the video stream is established, as a consequence it crashes.
If I add button to call run_landmarks function manually, wait to validate the webcam access, it works.

I do not exactly how to call run_landmarks and make sure the video stream is launched first. Tried several call using async/await but everytime, this does not seem to block the call to run_landmarks immediately. I also tried to add a .catch in the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) but I get a syntax error and not sure this is somethng that should be done.

What would be the most direct way to block the call to run_landmarks waiting for the video to be ok?

Thanks.

John

Comment: "*it crashes*" - what is the error message?

Comment: You seem to be waiting for `.getUserMedia(constraints)` just fine. Maybe you need to wait for the [`canplay` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) though

Comment: @bergi  face_mesh.js (a mediapipe file) raise this error: WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no video  . Meaning that the video is not launched yet.